# Local costmap static without any sensor information

Tags: ros, navigation, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am relatively new to ROS and don't have much experience it will be a great help if someone can answer my quetsion.

I am trying to move a robot around using a static map.  The global path plannig is correct but it is not showing local costmap (not considering obstacles).  I am not using any laser scanner but Kinect Fusion with a Kinect to creating the map and for pose estimation. Is it possible to inflate obstacles without use of any kind of sensor data.

In the [screenshot of rviz](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14629615642843198.png) you can see that the positions near the obstacles have low costs in the local costmap. Due to this the robot will move in the direction of the obstacle.

costmap configuration:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 3.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: true
  robot_footprint: [[0.13, 0.235], [-0.22, 0.235], [-0.35, 0.0], [-0.22, -0.235], [0.13, -0.235]]
  rolling_window: false
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.1

Global costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true

costmap_common_param
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  raytrace_range: 3.0
  footprint: [[0.13, 0.235], [-0.22, 0.235], [-0.35, 0.0], [-0.22, -0.235], [0.13, -0.235]]
  #robot_radius: ir_of_robot
  inflation_radius: 0.55
  transform_tolerance: 1.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234032/local-costmap-static-without-any-sensor-information/) by [sosuhui](https://answers.ros.org/users/26815/sosuhui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-10**:
Please post your costmap configurations by **editing** your question. Please put the configurations into a preformatted text (using the buttons with 101010 on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally figured out how to avoid obstacles in local planner while setting `rolling_window: false` and `static_map: true`.  You can copy map data in your custom layer and make it available for local planner.

---

Originally posted by [sosuhui](https://answers.ros.org/users/26815/sosuhui/) with karma: 11 on 2016-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To enable the inflation in static map, you have to add some plugins in your yaml such as :

```
   plugins:
     - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
     - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

You can refer to the turtlebot navigation yaml files if you need examples :
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/param/global_costmap_params.yaml

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sosuhui](https://answers.ros.org/users/26815/sosuhui/) on 2016-05-10**:
I applied the approach but it is not working.  I guess problem is not with plugins.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-10**:
This is due to the fact that you still use the old parameter layout above. I don't think a combination of old and new will work properly. Otherwise, you would also need to configure the plugins properly.

**Comment by [sosuhui](https://answers.ros.org/users/26815/sosuhui/) on 2016-05-17**:
@mig I had made changes in my config files.  Now these are arranged using plug-ins, but no use.  Can you please tell me, is navigation stack able to use static layer: true and rolling window: false and having no observation source set?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-17**:
the localcostmap should have `rolling_window: true` and `static_map: false`. If you do not specify any observation sources for the local costmap, it is "optimizing" the plan through the non-existing obstacles. I'm not sure if what you want can be done...

**Comment by [torkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/26543/torkx/) on 2016-05-30**:
That worked for me. Thanks. I just needed to get information from my created map to have the local costmap with the inflation layer.